# Facebook embeds loading the wrong language

Tags: headers, facebook, embed

The theme I am using has a function to embed videos from Facebook. The problem is that whenever I use it it loads the SDK in `uk_UA` for whatever reasons (Ukrainian).

Nothing related to my Website or Facebook is using this language. After contacting the theme developers i was told it's not their fault and *might* be something related to the server configuration.

I tried an hacky solution I found here with adding to the *funcitons.php* the following script

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'facebook_sdk_replace' );
function facebook_sdk_replace( $content ) { if ( is_single() ) { $content = str_replace("/uk_UA/", "/en_US/", $content); } return $content; }
```

As it had no effect, the developer suggested I should add to the _header_php the following

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

The problem I am facing is that by doing so, I am getting the following error:

*Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...*

Therefore, I reverted back my *header.php*.
Is there a way to fix this issue without altering the header?

Later edit:
The only code snippet I found is the following:

```
        /* $buffy = '
        <div class="wpb_video_wrapper td-facebook-video">
            <iframe src="' . td_global::$http_or_https . '://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=' . urlencode($videoUrl) . '&show_text=0" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true" ></iframe>
        </div>
        ';
        */

        /**
         * cache & oembed implementation
         */
        $cache_key = self::get_facebook_id($videoUrl);
        $group = 'td_facebook_video';

        if (td_remote_cache::is_expired($group, $cache_key) === true) {

            // cache is expired - do a request
            $facebook_api_json = td_remote_http::get_page('https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json/?url=' . urlencode($videoUrl) , __CLASS__);

            if ($facebook_api_json !== false) {
                $facebook_api = @json_decode($facebook_api_json);

                //json data decode
                if ($facebook_api === null and json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
                    td_log::log(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, 'json decode failed for facebook video embed api', $videoUrl);
                }

                if (is_object($facebook_api) and !empty($facebook_api->html)) {

                    //add the html to the buffer
                    $buffy = '<div class="wpb_video_wrapper">' . $facebook_api->html . '</div>';

                    //set the cache
                    td_remote_cache::set($group, $cache_key, $facebook_api->html, self::$caching_time);
                }

            } else {
                td_log::log(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, 'facebook api html data cannot be retrieved/json request failed', $videoUrl);
            }

        } else {
            // cache is valid
            $api_html_embed_data = td_remote_cache::get($group, $cache_key);
            $buffy = '<div class="wpb_video_wrapper">' . $api_html_embed_data . '</div>';
        }
        break;
```

Comment: It's not wordpress related question I suppose. Can you open source page of your site and find place where `connect.facebook` contains? We will try to suggest where you should make changes then

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by... error occurs if anything is added before headers sent using php's `header` function. Even a blank line or space will give this error.

Comment: @AntonLukin how can I ... open source a page ? I'd gladly do that. For now, here's an example: https://esportsmedia.ro/highlights/pubg/pan-power/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue was given on the [wordpress core ticketing system](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40656).

> This is probably something you should report to Facebook (good luck),
>   as WordPress is correctly outputting the lang attribute on the html
>   element. Facebook likely uses heuristics to determine if the actual
>   page language is indeed English or not when en_US is used, similar to
>   what Google Chrome does. This is the unfortunate situation that the
>   web finds itself in when services cannot trust web standards due to
>   incorrect implementations (ie. sites not in US English but still using
>   en_US as the lang). In your situation you may be able to make use of
>   the og:locale OpenGraph tag to persuade Facebook that your content
>   really is in US English.

Answer (score 1):

I've found your problem.

You've inserted video from facebook on your page with facebook init script.

[image: Take a look at language options]

Find the place where you insert this video and change uk_UA to en_US there.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. That's not being done manually in the theme files, but more like being pulled from an API or something. I tried searching for that one line in the entire server (in each file). Nothing came up

Comment: I added a code snippet of where the magic is happening. Nothing else came by when searching for _connect.facebook_

Comment: Try to find it in database. Select * from wp_posts where post_content like '%connect.faceboook%';

Comment: there's nothing like that in `wp_posts`. I tried to find a solution all this time. but nada